# BeautifulSoup: finding nested tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, nested, tags, screen-scraping

i am quite stuck with this:

```
<span>Alpha<span class="class_xyz">Beta</span></span>
```

I am trying to scrape only the first span text "Alpha" (excluding the second nested "Beta").
How would you do that?

I am trying to write a function to find all the Span tags without a class attribute, but something is not working...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
txt = """<doc>
<span>Alpha<span class="class_xyz">Beta</span></span>
</doc>"""
soup = bs(txt,'lxml')
target = soup.select_one('span[class]')
target.decompose()
soup.text.strip()
```

Output:

```
'Alpha'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way that get the text for every Span tag without a class attribute:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<body>
<p>Some random text</p>
<span>Alpha<span class="class_xyz">Beta</span></span>
<span>Gamma<span class="class_abc">Delta</span></span>
<span>Epsilon<span class="class_lmn">Zeta</span></span>
</body>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
target = soup.select("span[class]")
for i in range(len(target)):
    target[i].decompose()
target = soup.select("span")
out = []
for i in range(len(target)):
    out.append(target[i].text.strip())

print(out)
```

Output:

```
['Alpha', 'Gamma', 'Epsilon']
```

Or if you want the whole span tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<body>
<p>Some random text</p>
<span>Alpha<span class="class_xyz">Beta</span></span>
<span>Gamma<span class="class_abc">Delta</span></span>
<span>Epsilon<span class="class_lmn">Zeta</span></span>
</body>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
target = soup.select("span[class]")
for i in range(len(target)):
    target[i].decompose()
out = soup.select("span")

print(out)
```

Output:

```
[<span>Alpha</span>, <span>Gamma</span>, <span>Epsilon</span>]
```